# DeviceEventEmitter vs NativeAppEventEmitter

Tags: react-native, deviceeventemitter, nativeeventemitter

I want to use events to communicate between native ios/android and my react native app.

I see two ways to do this: DeviceEventEmitter and NativeAppEventEmitter, which seem to be fairly identical.

What's the difference between them? Why should I pick one over the other?

Answer (score 13):

Both `DeviceEventEmitter`and `NativeAppEventEmitter` are deprecated, you should use `NativeEventEmitter` instead.

Comment: It's in the source: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1490ab12ef156bf3201882eeabfcac18a1210352/Libraries/EventEmitter/RCTNativeAppEventEmitter.js#L15  & https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1490ab12ef156bf3201882eeabfcac18a1210352/Libraries/EventEmitter/RCTDeviceEventEmitter.js#L32

Comment: had a recent case where there was code with DeviceEventEmitter that worked in Android but not in iOS. Switched to NativeEventEmitter and it works in both.

Answer (score 4):

I've found I need to use both when developing cross-platform native extensions that need to send events from Java/Obj-C to JavaScript.

On iOS you send events to JS like this:

```
[self.bridge.eventDispatcher sendAppEventWithName:@"myProgressEvent" body:@{               
 @"progress": @( (float)loaded / (float)total )
}];
```

.. which you pick up in JS using `NativeAppEventEmitter`.

In Java you send events to JS with:

```
WritableMap map = Arguments.createMap();
map.putDouble("progress", progress);
getReactApplicationContext().getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
        .emit("myProgressEvent", map);
```

.. which you pick up in JS using `DeviceEventEmitter`

It's not ideal, as your JS code needs to then choose the right
emitter for the events to be received.

E.g.

```
    const emitter = Platform.OS == 'ios' ? NativeAppEventEmitter : DeviceEventEmitter;
    emitter.addListener("myProgressEvent", (e:Event)=>{
        console.log("myProgressEvent " + JSON.stringify(e));
        if (!e) {
            return;
        }
        this.setState({progress: e.progress});
    });
```

Comment: This is no reason to choose one over the other, because it's wrong. 

Check out iOS's RCTEventDispatcher's sendDeviceEventWithName, and React Native Android's com.facebook.react.modules.core.RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, you can send from both platforms to both event emitters.