# How to detect if a headphones / a headset is connected to an Android device in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am making a calling app where users may or may not use headphones / a headset. On an incoming video call I am using [react-native-incall-manager](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-incall-manager) to turn the speaker on / allow speaker phone. The basic `InCallManager.start({ media: 'video' });` method works and allows detection of a new audio device being plugged in such as headphones, and if this happens, the headphone and mic plugged in work as expected.

The problem comes in the case that headphones are already plugged in to the device before a call starts, because the `InCallManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);` method is called at that time. `InCallManager.start({ media: 'video' });` doesn't account for devices already connected and the headphones do not work, the normal speaker does even though headphones are plugged in.

[react-native-incall-manager](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-incall-manager) recommends using `DeviceEventEmitter` from react-native to detect native events such as changes in connected audio devices, but this module is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36692416/deviceeventemitter-vs-nativeappeventemitter).

Here it is recommended to use `NativeEventEmitter`, but this seems very complex and seems to require the native Java (Android) modules to be written and used in conjunction with it.

How can I detect changes in connected audio devices in Android in React Native?

Answer (score 1):

> Here it is recommended to use NativeEventEmitter, but this seems very complex and seems to require the native Java (Android) modules to be written and used in conjunction with it.

You don't need to write a native Java module for this job since `NativeEventEmitter` can pick up events that were sent through `RCTDeviceEventEmitter`.

So example from `react-native-incall-manager` README

```
import { DeviceEventEmitter } from 'react-native';

DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('Proximity', function (data) {
    // --- do something with events
});
```

can be easily rewritten to this

```
import { NativeEventEmitter, NativeModules } from 'react-native';

const eventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(NativeModules.InCallManager);
const eventListener = eventEmitter.addListener('Proximity', event => {
  // do something with events
});
```

Just don't forget to clean up once you no longer need event listeners

```
eventListener.remove();
```

If you want to detect changes in connected audio devices you can subscribe to `onAudioDeviceChanged` event from `react-native-incall-manager`.
It sends something like this whenever there is a change in connected audio devices or device that will output sound

```
{"availableAudioDeviceList": "[\"BLUETOOTH\",\"SPEAKER_PHONE\",\"EARPIECE\"]", "selectedAudioDevice": "EARPIECE"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try to implement this shortly

Comment: Its not working on android. Do you know any alternative?